# Why do disk names change at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

Previously, all of my disk partitions where called `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, ... My network stopped working (couldn't ping out), and after a `sudo ifdown eth0` and `sudo ifup eth0`, my desktop went away and my computer froze (Ubuntu 12.10, 32 bit - should have installed 64-bit, but too late to correct). After making a live boot CD, and mounting etc., I have now found that all my partitions are labelled `/dev/sde1`, `/dev/sde2`... I eventually got the system back through mounting the appropriate sdex's on `/mnt/dev`, `/mnt/sys`, `/mnt/proc`, etc., `chroot`, and `update-grub`, but I have no idea (and have not been able find using Google) any info on why names changed. Is anyone familiar with this? Thanks.
-Bi

Comment: "Is anyone familiar with this?" is not a real question asking for a specific advice or solution. Please state, what exactly you'd like to change about the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The internal disk identifiers aren't supposed to be stable in Linux. Therefore you should not rely on the names of `/dev/sd?*` to remain the same after reboot or after disconnecting and reconnecting a removable medium.

If you need to refer to a specific device in a script or configuration file, use device IDs, UUIDs, or file system labels as in `/dev/disk/`.