# Partition changes name after every reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

The partition on my C:(main ssd used for dual booting windows and Ubuntu) drive gets a different name almost every time I reboot. I want to make the partitions name permanent so I can safely link to files.

This is what my partitions name looks like:

```
/media/andrew/AC7A30A47A306D68/Program Files (x86)...
```

and here are the contents of my fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=5fcb9158-c68b-47c7-8fe7-e83ceba9cb99 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=CA2F-944D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Please help. I looked all over the Internet but only found these posts whose instructions I don't really understand. As here >
[Mount point name changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452640/mount-point-name-changed)
or here >
[Why do disk names change at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352704/why-do-disk-names-change-at-boot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command to determine the UUID of your `C:` drive:

```
sudo blkid
```

Example output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="f1b3915e-3c86-a3ec-3273-43967f134ce5" UUID_SUB="f48bf957-6f67-171f-ea75-29ddbd401637" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Win" UUID="28A139962EFFC093" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: UUID="571a61fe-6e6f-45d0-9fe1-832f28519f96" TYPE="reiserfs" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="f1b3915e-3c86-a3ec-3273-43967f134ce5" UUID_SUB="d0318ec5-9e4c-a864-7906-2d43bcbd0374" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" 
/dev/md0p1: UUID="88dc483f-aef9-454b-b744-2c3e3202a198" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/md0p5: LABEL="Home" UUID="b632fe56-564e-4d3f-833a-fde68fd1dd32" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/md0p6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="da84c996-f7d0-4fe8-8822-407e4f6c5c22" TYPE="ext4"
```

Find the device corresponding to your `C:` drive (use label if it's difficult) and add such line into your `/etc/fstab`:

```
 UUID=AC7A30A47A306D68 /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

Reboot (or do `sudo mount -a`) and see your drive mounted in `/windows`.

Comment: Awesome dude, working great, big thanks for your help.